# can't rebuild widget shown when downloading progress start flutter_downloader

Tags: flutter

Hi I'm trying to show different widget depending on the state of my attachment list
when not downloaded - download icon
when downloading in progress - circularprogressIcon / show the progress number
when done downloading - done icon

I manage to use the flutter_downloader and pass the data, but the problem is when we are still downloading the file, it didn't change to circular progress Icon it just stay in the download icon and suddenly when it's done the icon will be changed into done icon. How can I fix this ? I was able to print the progress on the terminal.

The problem is when i first attach the file, and then someone try to download it. It work just fine but when the other party delete it in their gallery and then tried to re-download it again, that's when the problem occur.

Here's my code:

```
                                progress == 0 ?
                                fileExistList[index] == true ?
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.done,
                                    color:
                                    floatingActionButtonColor,
                                    size: 19.0,
                                ) : GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    if (fileExistList[
                                    index]) {
                                      //Open file if it's already exist in the Local Path
                                      OpenFile.open(externalDir!.path +
                                          "/" +
                                          fileAttachmentList[index]['name']);
                                    } else {
                                      currentDownload =
                                      fileAttachmentList[index]['name'];

                                      final taskId =
                                      await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                                        url: fileAttachmentList[index]['url'],
                                        savedDir: externalDir!.path,
                                        showNotification: true,
                                        openFileFromNotification: true,
                                      );

                                      fileExistList[index] =
                                      true;
                                    }
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                      Icons.download,
                                      color:
                                      floatingActionButtonColor,
                                      size: 17.0),
                                )
                                    : currentDownload == fileAttachmentList[index]['name'] ?
                                    progress == 100 ? Icon(
                                    Icons.done,
                                    color:
                                    floatingActionButtonColor,
                                    size: 19.0)
                                    : Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets
                                      .only(
                                      right:
                                      4),
                                  child:
                                  SizedBox(
                                    child:
                                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                                      strokeWidth:
                                      2.0,
                                      valueColor:
                                      AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                                          floatingActionButtonColor),
                                    ),
                                    height:
                                    10.0,
                                    width:
                                    10.0,
                                  ),
                                )
                                    : fileExistList[index] == true
                                    ? Icon(
                                    Icons.done,
                                    color:
                                    floatingActionButtonColor,
                                    size: 19.0)
                                    : Icon(
                                    Icons
                                        .download,
                                    color:
                                    floatingActionButtonColor,
                                    size: 17.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through the official docs. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader
There are callbacks for getting the updation status.